# Objective-c newbie - UIViewController managedObjectContext unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext, managedobjectcontext

Using the code below I get the following error:

```
2016-04-25 10:04:51.520 eCoss[1700:620301] -[__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160383a0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x14f94500 (object 0x14d07b70, a NSException)
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0xffffffff sp=0x26a0b0] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x2 sp=0x26b980] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0xffffffff sp=0x26a0b0] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x2 sp=0x26b980] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x14f944e0 at 0x231e33b9
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: rethrowing current exception
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x6 sp=0x26b980] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: terminating
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x1 sp=0x26b820] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x1 sp=0x26b820] for exception 0x14f944e0
objc[1700]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x14f944e0 at 0x22a6f089
2016-04-25 10:04:51.582 eCoss[1700:620301] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160383a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x232d398b 0x22a6ee17 0x232d9325 0x232d6f51 0x232022f8 0x24dc0d9d 0x24dbffb1 0x5d06b 0x48f3d 0x48759 0x80a11 0x24d9b 0x27a70e61 0x27a70be7 0x27a70827 0x279e12fd 0x27a2ed13 0x279e12fd 0x27a2ed13 0x279e12fd 0x27a2ed13 0x27830e55 0x2786fde1 0x2786f593 0x27840055 0x2783e603 0x23295e6f 0x23295a5d 0x23293dcb 0x231e32e9 0x231e30d5 0x247d3ac9 0x278a80b9 0x1a4f1 0x22e8b873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

***CODE***

```
-(UIViewController*) displayViewFromString:(NSString *) identifier
{
     ontracAppDelegate* delegate = [ontracAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
     NSManagedObjectContext* moc = delegate.managedObjectContext;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Notes"]) {
        viewController = [[ontracPageNotesViewController alloc] init];

        NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://mydomain/%i/true",self.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id ];
        NSLog(@"%@", requestURL);
        //the request is built based on the string
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: requestURL]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSDictionary   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"CAKEPHP", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                      @"mydomain.co.uk", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                      self.cookieValue, NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                      @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                      nil];
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
        NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];
        NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

        NSError *err;
        NSURLResponse *resp;
        //the return data is formatted into a Json Response
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];



        NSMutableArray *responseObjects = [json objectForKey:@"response"];


        for (DataObject *dataObject in responseObjects) {
            //if ([dataObject.dataPack.pack_id intValue] == self.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id){
            NSArray * value = [responseObjects objectForKey:dataObject];
            //NSString *noteString = [[NSString alloc] init] ;
            NSString *noteCreated = [value objectForKey:@"created"];
            NSArray *imageArray = [value objectForKey:@"images"];
            NSString *noteString = [value objectForKey:@"note"];
            NSString * noteUpdated = [value objectForKey:@"updated"];

            NSLog(@"do %@", dataObject);

            Notes *note = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:moc];


            NSLog(@"%@", note);

            note.notes = noteString;
            note.noteID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: dataObject];
            //note.notes = self.textField.text;
            NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSString *image in imageArray) {

                NSString *image_created = [image objectForKey:@"created"];
                NSString *image_id = [image objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *image_data = [image objectForKey:@"image_data"];
                NSString *image_type = [image objectForKey:@"image_type"];

                NSLog(@"%@", image_id);

                NSData *pngData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:image_data options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
                NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%i_%@_notes_image.png", delegate.userName, self.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id, [self genRandStringLength:8]]]; //Add the file name
                [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

                [array addObject:filePath];

            }
            note.dataObject = dataObject;
            note.imageLocations = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
        NSLog(@"note %@", note);
            [dataObject addNotesObject:note];



        //}

      }

        //[[[splitView viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]  pushViewController:notesView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I have a line break at line (`note.notes = noteString`) which is when the error is produced. Prior to that the note object is logged fine. I just want to add the data i get from the request into it.

***CORE DATA***
[image: Core Data]

***Notes.h***

```
@class DataObject;

@interface Notes : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * imageLocations;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * noteID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataObject *dataObject;

@end
```

***Notes.m***

```
#import "Notes.h"
#import "DataObject.h"


@implementation Notes

@dynamic imageLocations;
@dynamic notes;
@dynamic noteID;
@dynamic dataObject;

@end
```

***managedObjectContext - appDelegate.m***

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext new];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
}

return managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: show an image of your core data model and the definition of the `Notes` entity class

Comment: @Wain Updated the question, think i got everything you asked for

Comment: does it crash on the first iteration of the loop, the second or some other random iteration?

Comment: @Wain First one everytime.

Comment: Can you please show the line after adding `exception break point`.

Comment: @byJeevan Line after the breakpoint is `note.noteID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: dataObject];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your issue is that your data types are all messed up. Your JSON stuff is listed as an `NSDictionary`, and you try to take out of that an `NSMutableArray`. It isn't possible for that array to me mutable with your current code.

You then iterate that array, and try to treat the contents as `DataObject` instances, but they will actually probably be `NSDictionary` instances.

You're also using `responseObjects objectForKey:dataObject`, apparently on an array, but that call should only work on a dictionary. You then continue to use `objectForKey` on what the code says is an array but again this should be a dictionary.

So, I'm kinda confused and unable to say exactly where this issue is, but I think you need to verify the class types that you're working with and make sure it's all what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Also show the code for your managedObjectContext creation.
Are you creating managedObjectContext in background thread?
From first line of crash it looks like your managed object context does not having access object with note with notes property.

```
 [__NSCFString managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160383a0
```

Finally verify that your JSON response will be proper and not having   entry.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the managedObjectContext creation. I can't answer your other questions though as I'm very new to xcode Obj-C and this is an existing project, not of my own creation.